# Execute code in background of Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification, notifications, background

I have a parser that calls a webserver to check if there are notifications to send. What would be the easiest way to implement backgrounding to Android and iOS so everyone would be able to receive the notification even when the app was terminated?

Comment: have you ever implemented mobile push before and have you decided whether you will use firebase or one signal or whatever for your push?

Comment: It was way easier for me to just parse the page mainly because a big group of people will receive other notifications according to what setting they choose.

Comment: Yeah so what exactly do you want from SO

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=vswin

Comment: My script to work even when somebody closes the app, like a messaging app that doesn't have to be always in foreground to send a push notification.